# How to change an item in an array?

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a Hangman Game for a school project and one of the requirements is to have the word displayed graphically. I am currently using a loop to add an underscore for every letter and a space for every space. When the user guesses a letter I need it to change all underscores that represent that letter into that letter. For example, if the word was "Stack Overflow" it would be `_ _ _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` and if they guessed `o` it would change to `_ _ _ _ _  O _ _ _ _ _ o _`. How would I change certain letters/characters in the array to allow me to change the letters?

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Hangman

    Dim UnderscoresStr() As Char
Dim GuessLength As Integer
Dim GuessedLetter As String
Dim WordLength As Integer
Dim RandomNum As String
Dim Category As String
Dim Word As String
Dim Letters() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}

Private Const EM_SETCUEBANNER As Integer = &H1501

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lParam As String) As Int32
End Function

Private Sub SetCueText(ByVal control As Control, ByVal text As String)
    SendMessage(control.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text)
End Sub

Public Function Random()
    Dim r As Random = New Random
    RandomNum = r.Next(1, 5)
    Return RandomNum
End Function

Public Function Underscores(Length)
    Dim WordArr() As Char = Word.ToCharArray()
    Dim UnderscoresText As String
    For i = 0 To Length - 1
        If WordArr(i) = " " Then
            UnderscoresText += " "
        Else
            UnderscoresText += "_"
            UnderscoresText += " "
        End If
    Next
    labelWord.Text = UnderscoresText
    Dim UnderscoresStr() As Char = UnderscoresText.ToCharArray
    Return UnderscoresText
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SetCueText(comboboxCategory, "Category...")
    SetCueText(textboxGuess, "Enter your guess...")
    buttonGuess.Enabled = False
    buttonGiveUp.Enabled = False
    textboxGuess.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub buttonStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonStart.Click

    Category = comboboxCategory.Text
    Dim Food() As String = {"Burger", "Pizza", "Fish And Chips", "Steak Pie", "Spaghetti"}
    Dim Animals() As String = {"Lammergeier", "Portia Spider", "Hagfish", "Demon Stingerfish", "Tapir"}
    Dim Movies() As String = {"Mrs Doubtfire", "Jurassic World", "Life Of Pi", "Fast And Furious", "Fury"}
    Dim FastFoodRestaurants() As String = {"Burger King", "KFC", "McDonalds", "Five Guys", "Costa"}
    Dim ChocolateBars() As String = {"Double Decker", "Mars Bar", "Twix", "Wispa", "Twirl"}

    If comboboxCategory.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select a category first!")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        labelGuessesLeft.Text = "Guesses Left: 6"
        buttonGuess.Enabled = True
        buttonGiveUp.Enabled = True
        textboxGuess.Enabled = True
        buttonStart.Enabled = False
        comboboxCategory.Enabled = False
    End If

    For i = 0 To 25
        listboxLettersLeft.Items.Add(Letters(i))
    Next

    Select Case Category
        Case "Food"
            Word = Food(Random())
        Case "Animals"
            Word = Animals(Random())
        Case "Movies"
            Word = Movies(Random())
        Case "Fast Food Restaurants"
            Word = FastFoodRestaurants(Random())
        Case "Chocolate Bars"
            Word = ChocolateBars(Random())
    End Select

    MsgBox(Word)

    WordLength = Len(Word)

    Underscores(WordLength)

End Sub

Private Sub buttonGiveUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonGiveUp.Click
    pictureboxHangman.Image = My.Resources.hangman_full
End Sub

Private Sub buttonGuess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonGuess.Click
    Dim WordArr() As Char = Word.ToCharArray()
    GuessedLetter = textboxGuess.Text
    GuessLength = Len(GuessedLetter)

    If GuessLength > 1 Then
        MsgBox("Please only enter a single letter!", 16, "Error!")
    Else
        If GuessedLetter Like "[a-z]" Then
            If listboxGuessed.Items.Contains(GuessedLetter) Then
                MsgBox("Please enter a letter you haven't already guessed!", 16, "Error!")
            Else
                listboxGuessed.Items.Add(GuessedLetter)
                listboxLettersLeft.Items.Remove(GuessedLetter)
                For i = 0 To WordLength - 1
                    If WordArr(i) = GuessedLetter Then
                        ** UnderscoresStr(i) = GuessedLetter **
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Please only enter a letter!", 16, "Error!")
        End If
    End If


   End Sub
End Class
```

I have put `**` before and after the piece of code I am trying to use to replace the character.

Anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: It looks correct.  Have you tried it?  Are you having any problems or getting any errors?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes, firstly I realised I forgot to re-define the text of the label to have the value of the array so I included `Dim UnderscoresStrString As String = String.Join("", UnderscoresStr) labelWord.Text = UnderscoresStrString` But now the label just shows as blank when I guess a letter. Not even any underscores show up.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to calculate the position in the array. As you're seperating each letter with a whitespace, every letter takes 2 positions (the whitespace + the actual letter).
It does seem like the position in your code is correct (using the for-loop).

It's possible to change the letter in the array, the same way as adding one.

```
ArrayName(5) = "k"
```

would change the 6th (0,1,2,3,4,5) element of the array, to the letter k.
"5" could be any integer, in rage of the array boundries (0 - arraylength - 1). If you'd like more information about manipulating arrays in VB.net, make sure to check [MSDN](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjXvcOQz-vKAhWobZoKHVIaBJwQFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F2x7h1hfk.aspx&usg=AFQjCNFDVRvtjaE3BrMLhuTDtJKuMNl6Pw&sig2=su1XQnykepSHCY-kyH6vyA).